# Maven JAR File need my src folder

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot project (maven, spring, angular, ...).

Now I have built a JAR file (`mvn clean package`), and i can execute it - all looks fine. But I can not see  my web page. Just an error `{"timestamp":1478852927238,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}`

But now, if i add the src folder (contains webapp, java, etc) in the same directory as my JAR file, all works fine. But I want my JAR file to be a standalone application without a src Folder. I have not worked so long with java, so i dont have any idea, what to do.

Comment: Did you add the Spring Boot Maven plugin to your POM?

Comment: Yes I did. But in my "application.jar" is not a folder named "webapp", i think, this is just missing

Comment: How does your project folder structure look like?